# How to handle a attribute with just two possible values

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema, normalization

In my web application i have a `company` which can be a `buyer` or a `supplier` or both.
So my database tables would be like this

```
Company( id_company, ..., is_buyer, is_supplier, ... )
```

Or :

```
Company( id_company, ... )
Type_company( id_type_company, type )
Extra_table(id_company, id_type_company )
```

Or :

```
Company( id_company, ... )
Type_company( id_company, id_type_company, type )
```

I want a explication (Pros and Cons) for every case if it's possible.

Comment: What do know of the pros and cons so far?

Comment: Is there any difference (other than the type designation) between buyers and suppliers?

Comment: For now there is no difference.

Comment: i didn't understand you @philipxy

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using the common supertype like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE companies
(
  id int not null primary key, 
  name varchar(128)
  -- other columns
);
CREATE TABLE buyers
(
  company_id int not null primary key,
  foreign key (company_id) references companies (id)  
);
CREATE TABLE suppliers
(
  company_id int not null primary key,
  foreign key (company_id) references companies (id)
);
```

Here are some sample queries:

```sql
-- Select all buyers
SELECT c.id, c.name
  FROM companies c JOIN buyers b 
    ON c.id = b.company_id;

-- Select all suppliers
SELECT c.id, c.name
  FROM companies c JOIN suppliers s 
    ON c.id = s.company_id;

-- Select companies that are both buers and suppliers
SELECT c.id, c.name
  FROM companies c JOIN buyers b 
    ON c.id = b.company_id JOIN suppliers s 
    ON c.id = s.company_id;

-- Select companies that are buers BUT NOT suppliers
SELECT c.id, c.name
  FROM companies c JOIN buyers b 
    ON c.id = b.company_id LEFT JOIN suppliers s 
    ON c.id = s.company_id
 WHERE s.company_id IS NULL;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fb98a/5)** demo

Recommended reading:

- [SQL Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557) by @BillKarwin

Comment: thanks for this good answer but can you update it and tell me why your solution is better that 3 possible solution that i wrote in my question ?

Comment: @Youssef You're welcome :) Out of three presented approaches I'd consider only first one if any. If you don't expect in one day with the necessity to implement also something like `is_vendor` you can get away with it.

Comment: @Youssef Now my proposed solution is a common pattern and is clean, self-descriptive, extensible (e.g. you can easily implement `is_vendor`), enforces foreign keys and is normalized.

Comment: yes i see that your solution is the best one just i'm afraid to create more tables and waste space and performence ... also if one day i have to implement also `is_vendor` so i just add it as attribute in `company` table ... correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: The proposed solution is most likely less wasteful since it's normalized  (not that it matters in this situation) as opposed to using flags in one table and might be faster depending on selectivity of index (indices) that you have to have on your flag columns. Depending on how your code is written changing the table schema (adding a new column) may break your code. But then again your approach with flag columns is viable and may be good enough for simple scenarios.

Comment: Your answer is excellent, but your arguments in support of it less so.  Normalization has nothing to do with the inclusion or not of boolean columns in the design.

Comment: @ErwinSmout Normalization has been mentioned only with regards to OP's concerns that the proposed approach will take more disk space. And normalization although not the only factor has everything to do with it. Other than that normalization is not a selling point for this design approach.